# How do you create component objects in React?

Tags: reactjs, components

I was playing around with `react-bootstrap` components and saw that their modals are structured like this:

```
<Modal>
  <Modal.Header>
    ...
  </Modal.Header>
  <Modal.Body>
    ...
  </Modal.Body>
</Modal>
```

I'm just curious, how are they able to create a react component that also holds sub-components such as `<Modal.Header>`? I'm making a lot of custom components in my project and I would love to structure a few of my components like this.

Comment: The beauty of JS is that everything is open source. You can read their code. If you are using it in a repo, you can navigate to the folder in node_modules. If not, you can check debug version as well: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/2.5.0/react-bootstrap.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
const Modal = () => <div>Modal</div>

Modal.Body = () => <div>Body</div>

export default Modal
```

And now you can use `<Modal.Body />`

Comment: Is this considered bad practice? It seems sort of odd storing the sub-components in the function object itself

Comment: If you dont abuse it and it does make sense that's not a bad practice. Functions in Js are objects like any other, so feel free to use that as your advantage.

Comment: Well, thank you then for the insight! This has helped a lot